# TinyMCE: Prevent link from inheriting selected font color?

Tags: css, hyperlink, tinymce, href

I'm using TinyMCE to style a span, but I have links within that span that I want styled by CSS. I have the `!important` declaration to ensure the CSS is used instead of what TinyMCE selects as the font's color. The problem I'm running into is if I use TinyMCE to alter the color of the span, TinyMCE also styles the links and overrides the CSS declaration. Here's the CSS I'm using on the links:

```css
    #todo-list .todo-text {
        color: #eeeeee;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }

    #todo-list .todo-text a {
        color: #ffba00 !important;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

How can I prevent TinyMCE from styling the links in the span?

Comment: where have you defined the css?

Comment: It's a Drupal site, and the CSS is in Drupal's default style template.

Comment: can you use firebug to check if it gets applied/overwritten?